# SSRS Datatype conversion based on label

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I am trying to add a pound symbol (£) to a value if the label column of that row fits a condition. Below is my expression but it isn't working. Can anyone tell me why?

```
=IIF(Fields!RowLabel = "Revenue For jobs Pain In (£)", "£"+CStr(Fields!Yesterday), Fields!Yesterday)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Value is missing in code. use this:

**=IIF(Fields!RowLabel.value = "Revenue For jobs Pain In (£)", "£"+CStr(Fields!Yesterday.value), cstr(Fields!Yesterday.value))**

Comment: Thanks very much, that's nailed it!